# How do I test what comes after a string

Tags: vb.net, find, richtextbox

I need to test what comes after "Text As" in a Rich Text Box. Anyone know how?

```
Private Sub DebugToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DebugToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Text_As As String
    Text_As = RichTextBox1.Find("Text As ")
```

I don't know what to do after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RichTextBox.Find doesn't return a String, it returns the index where the text was found (or -1 if not found). It's not clear how you want to check what follows "Text As ", but the following code checks to see if the remaining text begins with a given string.

```
Dim ind As Integer = RichTextBox1.Find("Text As ")
If ind >= 0 Then
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(ind + 8).StartsWith("Color Green") Then
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Also, how could I apply this to other properties, like location, font, size, etc.

Comment: @AndrewGarcia: I'm not sure what you mean by applying this to other properties. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: For example, I want to use this to make a label that is any color this way. I want to input "Text Color Green" and the text of the label will be green. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but I changed my answer to show how the text in Label1 can be changed to green if the RichTextBox contains "Text As Color Green".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Strings.Right` function:

```
Dim StringAfter = Strings.Right(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Text.Length - "Text As ".Length)
```

You basically take a number of characters from right side of the first argument. In this example I use the length of the text in the RichTextBox and substract the length of the string you want to get rid of.

Of course you can also directly insert the length of "Text As ", aka 7.

Comment: I get an error: Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero. (Sorry if it's an easy fix...)

Comment: This probably happens when the Text in the RichTextBox is shorter than 7 characters. Just check for this since in that case there isn't even the search string in the box.